# Split a field in two separate fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have a huge sewer network with pipe information, labelled for example as "pvc400" (where material=Pvc and diameter=400). Is it possible to split up the information into text and numbers only, so that i create two new columns, 1 with information about material "pvc" and one with the diameter "400"?

Comment: Will the structure of your field always be that 'simple' ?

Comment: yes, always pvc400, pvc200, ac200...

Answer (score 6):

To calculate that fields you can use regex function `regexp_substr()`. In the field calculator create new field with expressions:

1. For retrieving text characters (non-digits)

   ```
   regexp_substr("your_field",'(\\D+)')
   ```

This takes from "pvc400" only "pvc"

2. For retrieving numbers (digits) with

   ```
   regexp_substr("your_field",'(\\d+)')
   ```

This takes from "pvc400" only "400"

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!! works perfectly